# Laravel eloquent one to one through (level/tree) relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I'm new to laravel (eloquent). I'm trying to make **one to one through (level/tree) relationship** using eloquent ORM. I have `product_category` table that have `id` and `parent_id`.

This is my `product_category` table

```
|-----|--------|-----------|
| id  |  name  | parent_id |
|-----|--------|-----------|
|  1  |  book  |     0     |
|  2  |notebook|     1     |
```

This is my `product` table

```
|----|----------------|-------------|
| id | name           | category_id |
|----|----------------|-------------|
|  1 | super notebook |      2      |
```

I want to be able to pull parent category information from subcategory_id info in product alone. Is this possible?

When using SQL, this is the query (assume `category_id` is 2)

```
SELECT * FROM  `product_category` WHERE  `id` = (SELECT  `parent_id`  FROM `product_category`  WHERE  `id` =  '2' )
```

**Update:**

This is my current implementation

```
<?php

    class Product extends Eloquent {

        public function subcategory()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('ProductCategory');
        }

        public function category()
        {
            // This should get the parent info of the subcategory
            return ProductCategory::find($this->subcategory->parent_id);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -5):

A basic 1-2-1 relationship is done like this:

***Product model***

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Category');
    }

}
```

***Category model***

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }

}
```

Now you can query for data like this:

```
Product::find(1)->category;
```

Generated SQL:

`select * from products where id = 1`

`select * from categories where product_id = 1`

Basically you should rename your columns to match laravels defaults, else set the keys like `$this->hasOne('Category', 'foreign_key');`

[See docs also](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one)

Comment: I've done that, the problem is the relationship only works on subcategory. I want the relationship to go through category (which is in the same table as the subcategory itself). Sorry if it's rather confusing, you could look at my sample tables for better understanding